# Does RSpec require openstruct?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some strange behaviour in a small command line ruby app that parses cron strings.

I use an OpenStruct in part of my code and I forgot to `require "ostruct"`. My tests ran green and the code using OpenStruct is well tested.

However when I attempted to run the application 'as a user' from the command line I receive a `uninitialized constant CronParser::OpenStruct` error. I have added `require "ostruct"` and all is well again.

RSpec is bringing in OpenStruct and so my tests are not failing. But the application does not work. Clearly not ideal.

I would appreciate any thoughts on how I should be testing for this?

Thanks in advance.
T

Comment: Are you sure it's rspec and not another gem? I get a NameError when I enter OpenStruct after requiring rspec.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I totally missed that. I am running Simple Cov too to tell me about my test coverage. If I remove that it fails as expected.